# Spring, Spring Data JPA: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Test is not mapped

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

im getting a `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Test is not mapped` when i create a method in a Spring Data JPA Reposiotry that uses the [`@Query`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) annontation and Spring Data JPA validates it.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Test is not mapped [SELECT t from Test t]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:331)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86)
    ... 47 more
```

The repository looks like this:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Long>{

   Test findByDescriptionContaining(String text); //works

   @Query("SELECT t from Test t") //fails
   Test getOr();

}
```

What is interesing is that i can use Spring Data JPA Method name resolving and this queries work. Also when i add new fields to the Entity and have hbm2ddl.auto set to update changes are persisted to DB. But queries with the `@Query` annotation are not working.

My persistence configuration looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.company", entityManagerFactoryRef = "localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean")
@ComponentScan("com.company")
public class PersistenceJPAConfig {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceJPAConfig.class);

   @Bean
   @DependsOn("dataSource")
   public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
      return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   @DependsOn("dataSource")
   public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
      return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
   }

   @Bean
   public MailSender mailSender(){
      final MailSenderImpl mailSenderImpl = new MailSenderImpl();
      mailSenderImpl.setDataSource(dataSource());
      return mailSenderImpl;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
      config.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;DatabaseName=mydb");
      config.setUsername("user");
      config.setPassword("pass");
      config.setPoolName("HikariCpConnectionPool");
      config.setMaximumPoolSize(50);
      config.setMinimumIdle(2);
      return new HikariDataSource(config);
   }

   @Bean
   @DependsOn({"dataSource"})
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      em.setDataSource(dataSource());
      em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{
         "com.company.**.*"
      });
      em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
      em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
      return em;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
   }

   private Properties additionalProperties() {
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.use_sql_comments", "false");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
      properties.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");
      return properties;
   }

}
```

UPDATE : the Test entity. Base entity has `@Id Long id` and is a `@MappedSuperClass`

```
@Entity(name = "test")
public class Test extends BaseEntity{

   public Test() {
   }

   @Column(name = "description")
   private String description;
```

Comment: Is `Test` class annotated with `@Entity`?

Comment: Yes, it is annotated with @Entity.

Comment: In which package did u place the `Test` entity

Comment: The package is: `com.company.test`. However i have found that when i have `packagesToScan`  `com.company.**.*` it will search all packages underneath `com.company.`

Comment: Also, provide us with the code to `Test` class.

Comment: I would suggest that you follow your advice and scan all classes inside `com.company` (e.g., `@ComponentScan("com.company.*")`).

Comment: Your entity is named `test` not `Test`. You are overriding the default name in your `@Entity` annotation. Your query should be `select t from test t`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
@Entity(name = "test")
public class Test extends BaseEntity { ... }
```

In your entity you specify a `name` attribute overriding the default naming (the use of the name of the class). Hence your query is wrong, your query expects an entity named `Test` but that isn't available.

You have 2 possible solutions

1. Remove the `name` attribute and leave the query as is.
2. Change the query to `select t from test t` (notice the `t` instead of `T`).

Subsequently your return type is also wrong as it will return a collection of elements and not a single element. So change that to `List<Test>`.

Comment: F**k. You are right. l thought the `name` defines the table name in the db. I forgot that the `@Table` annotation does this. 4 years exp in JPA ;) Accept.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `*` in the setPackagesToScan  property and simply use - `em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.company"});`

Comment: Thank you very much, in my case there was a refactoring which moved entity classes to more specific package and `setPackagesToScan` was also changed to look at this package. Though some parts of the project was not moved to new package and as a result I was getting error regarding unknown entity type.

Answer (score 1):

Use like below if the name of the table is test in database

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List`  to get all object

```
@Query("SELECT t from Test t") //fails
List<Test> getOr();
```

Because `SELECT t from Test t` fetch all rows from database .

Comment: Please what you say ?

Comment: I changed the method in the repository to `List<Test> getOr();` but it is not working - i still get the same error.

Comment: set `properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");` then look the query what going wrong query.